# How to input only the first time in a while loop

Tags: bash, input, while-loop

I have a `while-read loop` that runs my script in Terminal. If I inserted an `echo` and `read` command pair into the script, I'd get prompted for input for each file in the directory that the script is looping through.

I want to avoid this obviously, but at the same time I don't want to have to hard type the target directory that my script is generating CSVs into, which is an inelegant solution and means for each new target directory, the script has to be tweaked again.

This is my `while loop` command in Terminal:

```
while read MS; do (cd "$MS" && bash script && cd ..); done <whichMSS.txt
```

And `/targetDirectory/` is the part of the script that needs inputting:

```
exiftool -csv -Title -Source $PWD > /targetDirectory/${PWD##*/}".csv"
```

The actual result is that I'd get prompted for input for each file as my script is iterating over them, which kind of defeats the purpose of the `while loop`. The ideal result would be to input `/targetDirectory/` for the first time only and not get prompted any more until all the files have been looped through. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Just place the input outside of your while loop

Comment: Why hadn't I thought of that! I was running the script inside the while loop as a one-line command in Terminal. Thanks to your thinking outside the box, I placed the
```echo``` and ```read``` pair outside the ```while loop``` and incorporated the script inside the while loop all as one, more comprehensive script. Now it takes input the first time and then loops through all the files till the very end. No need to run the ```while loop``` separately either. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it has helped!